# Issues scraping dynamic site (PhantomJS)

Tags: javascript, curl, phantomjs, wget

I am trying to find a way to wget/download a [website](https://www.sagedining.com/menus/admiralfarragutacademy).

I have tried `wget` and `curl` but no luck, then I've been led to `PhantomJS`.

```
var url = 'https://www.sagedining.com/menus/admiralfarragutacademy';
var fs = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        var html = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        });
        try {
            fs.write("/root/choate/page.html", html, 'w');
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

When I run this code on my Debian VPS,

```
sudo xvfb-run -- phantomjs menu.js
```

It downloads the site when it's still loading, and therefore only downloads the loading screen.
It also throws this error every time it runs:

> TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.
>
> TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.

Is there any way to download this website after it loads all the menus? Does the error message have anything to do with it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: im not familiar with phantomjs, but why you dont wait some seconds with `setTimeout` , to make sure web is loaded? something like the main example: https://phantomjs.org , also if you dont want to wait fixed seconds, you can use `setInterval` to check if page datas is loaded fully or not.

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming from PhantomJS because the page code is trying to set some properties in the DOM and maybe it does not have access to them. You should wait for the loading to happen, you can do it using  timeout function:

```
   if (status === 'success') {
   window.setTimeout(function () {
        var html = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    });
    try {
          fs.write("/root/choate/page.html", html, 'w');
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
    }, 1000); //Increase the value if you need more time
   }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that the web page that you are scraping has an incompatiblity issue with the PhantomJS engine, maybe there is a way to bypass that error.

Comment: even on a 15000ms timeout though, it doesnt seem to actually take 15 seconds to actually wait.

Comment: Yes, the issue you are having is not because of the timeout. It won't ever load because it is failing because of some JS function that is not allowed in PhantomJS. There are some Bugs reported on the [PhantomJS forum](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13895) about it